# Google Cast SDK iOS - Labels language doesn't respect device Lanaguage

Tags: google-cast, google-cast-sdk

I integrate the Google Cast SDK iOS sender app into my iOS application.
All the labels that the SDK shows are always in English. But I need those which the SDK shows to be in another language. The Android SDK applied the device language but the iOS SDK doesn't do so.

For example : 
"cancel" or "stop casting" in [first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQnmc.png) 
"Touch to cast media to your TV" in the [second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gqp4Y.png).

Could you please tell me how I can change language to all cast SDK iOS label?

Comment: What labels are you talking about? About Audio track language titles?

Comment: I'm talking about labels in SDK sections like "cancel" or "stop casting" in first image or "Touch to cast media to your TV" in the second image.

Comment: @ElenaVolpi Have you found a solution for this?